# How can I found the index of a array of characters in a string without looping on the array characters

Tags: javascript

i'm searching a simple way to find the index of one character / string between a list of characters.

Something which looks like

```js
"3.14".indexOf([".",","])
"3,14".indexOf([".",","])
```

Both should return `1`.

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
const testRegex = /\.|,/
const match = testRegex.exec("3.14");
console.log(match && match.index)
```

It uses a regular expression to search for either character, and uses the `exec` method on regular expressions which returns an object that has the index of the start of the match.

Comment: Why not simply use [`search`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) instead?

Comment: I had no idea search existed!

Comment: Thanks ! wow -3 I don't thought my question was so stupid :)

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the array and return the first character's index whose index is not `-1`:

```js
function getIndex(str, array){
  for(e of array){
    let index = str.indexOf(e);
    if(index != -1){
      return index;
    }
  }
}

console.log(getIndex("3.14", [".",","]))
console.log(getIndex("3,14", [".",","]))
```

You can also use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
function getIndex(str, array){
  return array.reduce((a,b) => a == -1 ? a = str.indexOf(b) : a, -1)
}

console.log(getIndex("3.14", [".",","]))
console.log(getIndex("3,14", [".",","]))
```